# how to get value from a web site using beautifulsoap in python?

Tags: python

Im trying to get words with headers from web site with beautifulsoap in python but I couldnt do it.
I'm trying to make a german dictionary.

Here is the site

**https://almancakonulari.com/a1-seviye-almanca-kelimeler/#gsc.tab=0**

I'm trying to pull data from the word Hallo, but `h3` tags come in between, I want to take these tags and use them as identifiers, so I'm trying to create a data set like this.

```
 [
     {
      "zahlen":[
        {
            "index": "1.",
            "word": "Hallo",
            "meaning": "Merhaba"
        },
        {
            "index": "2.",
            "word": "Herzlich willkommen",
            "meaning": "Hoş geldiniz"
        },
        {
            "index": "3.",
            "word": "Auf Wiedersehen",
            "meaning": "Hoşça kalın"
        }
      ]
     }
    ]
```

**hear is my code but my code doesnt work properly.**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import json



myList = [
    "jeden Tag",
    "Zahlen",
    "Tage – Monate",
    "Jahreszeiten-Farben",
    "Am Flughafen",
    "Im Hotel",
    "Im Restaurant",
    "Transport",
    "Zug",
    "Taxi",
    "Im weg",
    "Theater",
    "Kleidungsladen",
    "Elektrofachgeschäft",
    "Kosmetika",
    "Coiffeur",
    "Buchhandlung",
    "Post",
    "In der Arztpraxis",
    "Polizei",
    "Sport",
    "Zubehör ",
    "Wichtige Verben  Önemli Fiiller",
    "Im Supermarkt  Süpermarkette",
    "Verkehrszeichen",
    "Almanca Tur Kelimeleri"
]


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
url = "https://almancakonulari.com/a1-seviye-almanca-kelimeler/#gsc.tab=0"

result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, 'html.parser')
div = soup.find('div', class_='entry-content clearfix')

array = []
list={}

i=0
for h3_tag in range(len(myList)):

    list[myList[h3_tag]] = []
    tempObj = {
     "identifier": myList[h3_tag]
    }
    tempArr = []
    words = div.find_all('table',class_='table table-bordered')[i]
    for word in words:
        for word1 in word.find_all('tbody'):
            rows = word1.find_all('tr')
            for row in rows:
                each_word = row.find_all('td')
                tempArr.append({
                    "index": each_word[0].string,
                    "word": each_word[1].string,
                    "meaning": each_word[2].string
                })
    tempObj["words"] = tempArr
    array.append(tempObj)
    i+=1



with open('almancaKelimeler1.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(array, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

how can I do this ?

when i run the current code i get this error:

`AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'. Did you mean: '_find_all'?`

but when I remove

`words = div.find_all('table',class_='table table-bordered')`**`[i]`**

for example like this

`words = div.find_all('table',class_='table table-bordered')`

in this case there is no error but it brings all the words for each identifier. i.e. it needs to fetch 1000 words in total but returns 1000 words for each title or identifier

Comment: What does "doesn't work properly" mean? Do you get an error? Unexpected result? Please, provide more detail on your issue and see [ask].

Comment: when i run the current code i get this error: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'. Did you mean: '_find_all'? but when I remove [i] index end of the div.find_all while finding words, it brings all the words for each identifier. i.e. it needs to fetch 1000 words in total but returns 1000 words for each title or identifier

Comment: How can I get the index words ?. I understood what the problem was, it enters the loop every time, because I say find_all, it pulls all the words. each time.